# What is the term for a cut from one close-up object to another absurdly similar close-up object?

Tags: terminology, editing

What is the term for a cut from one close-up object to another absurdly similar close-up object? For example, in the movie "A Christmas Story", I think there is a cut from a close-up of a toilet lid closing, to a close-up of a kitchen cooking pot lid opening, momentarily fooling the viewer into thinking it's one continuous scene, and then bringing on thoughts of mild disgust and humor over the absurd juxtaposition.

Comment: See also - https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/16429/25773 https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/106596/25773 and https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33818/25773

Comment: @F1Krazy answered well bellow, but I just wanted to clarify that there is no need for the two shots to be close-ups. The famous match cut in Lawrence Of Arabia is from a close-up of a matchstick to a landscape shot of a sunrise.

Answer (score 8):

TV Tropes (obligatory warning - it's a massive time sink) calls this a [Match Cut](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MatchCut):

> A cut or dissolve that matches an object in the first shot with an object in the second shot. The objects must be similar in size and position within the shot. Can be used to add harmony and continuity to a sudden shift in time or place.

The article lists the example you provided from *A Christmas Story*:

> *A Christmas Story* cuts from Randy opening the toilet to the boys' mother opening a pot of dinner.